# Jquery check whether element is hidden (continuously)

Tags: jquery, function, element, visibility

How to check whether a element is made to hide at once. i.e how to notify the visibility of an element.

In my case, the element is made to hide by `slideUp` function. At once i should be notified about the visibility of the that element.

I got the idea of using `bind()` method. But it does not have a `onHide` like event. So how to get like this ? any suggestions will be helpful !

**EDIT:**

I know it is possible to use `is(':hidden')` but i want to check continuously like `addEventListener`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
if($('#selector').is(':visible')){
   //is visible
}else{
  //is NOT visible threfore is hidden
}
```

**EDIT**
if that does not exist
then you will have to check for opacity/filter property

so

```
if($('#selector').css('opacity')!=0){
       //is visible//or partially visible//depends on opacity
    }else{
      //is NOT visible threfore is hidden
    }
```

also make sure you check opacity cross browser

**EDIT 2**

```
function checkVisibility(){
   //put the visibility checker here
   setTimeout('checkVisibility',1000)//every 1 second...
}
```

note: that repetitions like this MIGHT slow down the browser

Comment: yes this is good, but i want to check it continuously.. how to check it ?

Comment: use a setInterval or setTimeout...check Edit 2 in a minute

Comment: Dont pass string, do like this: `setTimeout(checkVisibility,1000)`/

Comment: thnx @cipi I have been working on regex recently and my head is all over the place :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use slideUp's callback to know at once when the element is hiden:

```
function theElementIsHidden()
{
    //What to do when the slideUp animation (element hidden) is completed...
}

$("#element").slideUp(200, function(){theElementIsHidden();}
```